Why do some nations hold close ties with their former colonies and some don't?
Lots of European nations hold close ties with their former colonies after their independence, such as the Netherlands with Indonesia, Suriname and South Africa; the UK with Malaysia, UAE, America, New Zealand, and other Commonwealth nations; Portugal with East Timor and Brazil; France with Vietnam and Cambodia; Spain with Mexico, Venezuela, Peru, and so on. I'd like to ask why they hold close ties after the nation's independence; involving themselves in the development of these nations. Some examples: France funding schools and universities in Cambodia; the Netherlands sending some vaccines to Indonesia, and accepting Indonesian students to universities, at least before the abolition of national exams in Indonesia (I don't think it's that easy anymore); Britain investing in the UAE.
Another thing is that some of these nations hold no animosity or 'grudge' towards their former colonizers after their independence. I know that some have had a rough journey to smooth their relations, but I do wonder about those nations who have moved on, how and why they can move on so easily.
It amazes me that these nations form diplomatic ties, and I'd like to know why. And why some don't seem to get along with their former colony or former colonizer, such as France and Algeria, or Belgium and the DRC (Democratic Republic of Congo).

Welcome to Politics.SE! There seem to be three separate questions here: why some countries have close ties with their former colonies; why those colonies are so willing to accept those close ties; and why some colonies don't get along with their former colonizers. I would recommend narrowing this down to focus on just one of those things, and perhaps asking the others separately. [1/2]

[2/2] In the case of Algeria and DR Congo, though, the reasons they don't get along with France and Belgium respectively should be fairly obvious just from reading up on what those specific countries went through. (This isn't exclusive to Western empires either: China and especially Korea still hate Japan for what they went through as Japanese colonies.)

@F1 Let's no go overboard with the multiple-Q metrics, esp with a new user.  Would you like to see Q1:  why don't they get along?  Q2:  why do they get along? Q3:  why are they collaborating?  By most people's undertanding these are two sides of the same coin  and I suspect the Q1-Q2-Q3 approach would end up in some duplicate closures.  Good question, as it influences much of the world today.

"it amazes me that these nations form diplomatic ties" It doesn't amaze me. They are culturally linked. Why should any two nations form diplomatic ties. Obviously there is an advantage to it.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution to clarify, it amazes me because despite tense and bitter history they still want to cooperate and start anew

@ItalianPhilosopher I'd like to know Q1 and Q2 most, as those are my main questions in this post

What I meant is that the three questions are not individual questions.  They, together, make for an interesting question:  what decides how friendly or antagonistic relations are?  Best kept in one post, as you did.  I would not want to have these 3 subdivided into 3 posts, because there is so much redundancy.  Welcome to SE.Politics where, yes, some of us hold different opinions about what constitutes the best format for a question.  The question, or questions, are A-OK though.

"despite tense and bitter history" See Germany and France for example, not colonies, but certainly tense and bitter history, but also neighbors and on a cultural level linked in many ways. Curiosly diplomatic ties between France and Germany were knotted after WW2 exactly to avoid a repetition of the bloody history.

Colonisation was not exclusively a destructive thing, mass slavery and so on. Sometimes it was, sometimes it was more like an alliance. Even if there were black spots in the mutual history (mostly, there were), still many contacts were created and they can exist forever for the profit of both countries.

The answer is different for different colonizer-former colonies. It would be helpful if you could narrow it down to, say, France and its former colonies in the Sahel. I agree with @ItalianPhilosopher that it is okay asking what you did, but to give you a meaningful answer in the StackExchange format, rather than writing a book, we need to have more focus in the question.

@EllieK I'll ask for Germany and Israel for now, or Vietnam with France and USA. Because I want to find cases similar to the one I'm concerned right now, in hopes of calming me down by a possible future. I'd like to know how these nations moved on and how some of them show their apology and regrets for their sins with them

Your user name is so sweet! I smile when I see it. Vietnam with France is interesting, although I don't know if they still have a good relationship. France with Algeria/Tunisia/Haiti is a good example. Vietnam and the USA didn't have a colony-colonizer relationship nor did Germany and Israel. What are you concerned about right now, if I may ask? There's plenty of reason for concern in general, I agree!

@EllieK Thanks :) I couldn't think of any other username, and I came to Politic S.E bc im anxious of politics.  im concerned about a silent conflict in one of the areas of my nation. To put it simply: some obscured info proved that its not supposed to be a part of this nation, and it has soo many disturbing things happening. which is why I ask about the relationship between Vietnam with France & USA, and Israel and Germany. Despite not being colonizers they had horrible history with the other, and seeing how they can move on, I wonder if it can happen with my nation in the future

Is that not simply because international relations are so close to marital relations, writ large? Many divorces dissolve into acrimony; others end in lasting friendship.

Different nations have different histories as colonizers, colonized, and decolonized. So there are different factors at work:

There are a few former colonies where the current population and political culture is mostly derived from the colonizers, e.g. Canada or New Zealand. Independence movements were about the political independence of the colonizers from the homeland, not so much about throwing out colonizers or restoring the rights of the indigenous people (some of that came later, as a domestic debate).
There are more former colonies where the current population is mostly based on the indigenous people, and independence movements were about throwing colonizers out or at the very least restricting their political power to their proportion of the electorate, e.g. India, Malaya or Indochina. How this turned out depends in large part on how gracefully the colonizers left.
There are a few sort-of-colonies which are still legally connected to their former colonial powers, and do not wish independence, e.g. Saint Pierre and Miquelon, Greenland, Puerto Rico, the Falklands. Calling them "colonies" has become unfashionable, and mostly the people do not want the loss of their current status. In a few cases, this is still under debate.

This history obviously influences the present-day relations.

There are former colonies where the language of the former colonizing powers is still heavily used, e.g. francophone parts of Africa, much of the Americas, much of the Commonwealth of Nations. This gives people from these former colonies an advantage trading with or migrating to the former colonial power simply because they speak the same language.
In some cases, these ties are institutionalized with preferential trade and visa agreements.
In some cases, the former colonial powers continued to pay pensions to indigenous staff.

There are both highly emotional and utilitarian factors to the relations between the former colonizers and the former colonies. Read about comparative advantage to understand why international trade can benefit both sides. Such trade is easier if one speaks the language, if legal systems use the same traditions, etc. So when a former colonial power lets students from the former colonies in, they both uphold the emotional ties and bring tangible benefits for both sides.
But if the decolonization has been very hostile, those ties were cut.

Extra twists:  Caribbean countries aren't indigenous-populated, but rather the descendants of African slaves, so a different category.  Most of them get along fairly well, as slavery was abolished way earlier than in the US and there was no Jim Crow follow up.  Budgetary assistance smooths things over as well.  South America had a bloody war in 1830s and the (minority?) indigenous population was horribly ill treated, but relations with Spain - which has a policy of engagement - are generally good by now.  Time does heal things and so, I think, does contemporary development in the ex colony.

...Porto Rico and the Philippines have a history with the US, but they were also liberated from Spanish's colonial rule by the US (so was Cuba, but that went another way).

@ItalianPhilosopher, I would have said that the Caribbean population is to a significant degree mixed. But that is where race as a social construct comes in. And if Puerto Rico and the Philippines were liberated or simply changed colonizers is another interesting question -- the independence of the Philippines was just starting when WWII came.

I grew up in St Maarten and I can assure you that, once you take out all the civil servants sent in from France and Holland, as well as the tourists/short timers, the great bulk of the not-so-recent population is Black.  Certainly with some mixing and a leavening of resident whites, but, Black otherwise.  I can also assure you that - though we all got along very well - if you were to chat of "race as a social construct" there, you'd get a resounding WTF???  Not in the sense of grievance or intolerance, just WTF for a very, very, academic turn of phrase that makes limited sense to most ppl

does the severity of the colonialism/occupation dictates how well their relationship would be? China & S.Korea still have bitter ties with Japan because of WW2. But how come some of the colonizers and colonies don't seem to be bothered by the severity of their colonialism? How come Philippines seems to forgive or 'moved on' easily from USA? or how come Brazil can move on and forgive Portugal quite easily? Aren't all of their colonialism severe—involving slavery and other things?  Or are they not as bad as they made it out to be or just 'censor' the severity in the history textbooks?

@ItalianPhilosopher, the day before yesterday I had a chat with somebody about how Dutch I am. Go back five generations and you get people on either side of the border. But being able to trace some part of the family tree to a 16th century Frisian doesn't really affect how I identify. Things are different when other people ascribe ethnic origin based on how one looks.

@AnxiousSocialStudiesStudent, Brazil became independent after the Portugese monarchy fled there during the Napoleonic wars, created a government in exile, and left a prince there when it went back. A very unusual case, but you will always find unique elements.

@AnxiousSocialStudiesStudent It feels you desperately want to find one single factor (e.g., "severity" of colonial crimes) that neatly explains current-day relations for all ex-colonies. The world is usually not so simple. You need to look at it case by case.

@xLeitix im trying to grasp the idea of diplomatic relationships between Colonizer and Ex-colony. One of the things that came to mind was the ones where the colonialism was so brutal, I genuinely wonder how the colony can still forgive and continue a diplomatic relationship. I do know that not all cases are the same and the circumstances definitely affect the further relations. this is not just for my own desire for knowledge but also for my writings. oh and some of my political concerns too—things are not looking good here

@AnxiousSocialStudiesStudent Well, you got a lot of good answers that talk about many different aspects that may influence these relations. I suggest that "severity of brutalities committed, often in a relatively distant past" are probably among the least important ones in practice (except when they are instrumentalized as part of a campaign that has other actual goals).

@AnxiousSocialStudiesStudent not a case of colonialism, but consider that Germany and Israel have a very good relationship these days, and so does Germany and France. Even the most extreme brutalities can be forgiven surprisingly quickly, if the circumstances are right and both parties profit from forgiveness.

@AnxiousSocialStudiesStudent Be careful about your own prejudices here. The concept of colony/colonizer through the lens of identity politics is very recent. Not all colonizers were brutal, not all colonies were oppressed. Even instances that we label as brutal in modern context may not have been considered brutal in historical context. You might find more information in comparing/contrasting each individual colony and the cause for the independence movement. See which ones succeeded and which ones failed and why.

@DavidS I'd be highly curious to know which colonies started out happily.  For example, much of Europe has a fairly benign view of Roman occupation.  But that's only with a lot of hindsight:  the first few generations in Gaul went through a meat grinder at the time.  For sure, there may be some exceptions, but "lens of identity politics" seems quite problematic as a generalization.  Not everything is due to "modern sensibilities".

Actually, the reason why Canada gained full independence from the UK was because the French and Catholic part, Quebec, wanted to leave rest of the country, being English and traditionally Protestant. The 1982 Constitution act was a result of the unsuccessful 1980 Quebec secession referendum.

@DavidS That's an insightful statement, thank you. I sometimes forget how much of these social concepts or social structures have different stigma/reputation or meaning in different lens; in a way, what you said really reassured me of my political worries :)
I apologize for my ignorance in advance.

@xLeitix I completely forgot about Germany. It's really interesting what you said 'Even the most extreme brutalities can be forgiven surprisingly quickly, if the circumstances are right and both parties profit from forgiveness'. I'm curious about the last stance about both parties profiting forgiveness. thank you for the statement, it may not solve my overarching political concern but it did give me a little hope to pull me out of my seas of political concern once in a while; it'll be a good reminder. thank you!

"But if the decolonization has been very hostile, those ties were cut." In general, quite true. But there is atleast one glaring counter example with the US-UK relationship.

@ouflak, the ties between the US and UK remained strained for three or four generations. Time for memories to subside.

"...the ties between the US and UK remained strained for three or four generations." Indeed, there was even another war fought between the two! But the O.P. doesn't seem to provide a time limit on when the change to former-colony status occurred. And we are sadly living in a world where many people are committing themselves to violence, and even war, atleast partly for revenge of events that place centuries earlier.


Historical and Cultural Links
Former colonies often maintain strong linguistic and cultural ties with their former colonizers, shaping modern relationships. Take, for example, the relationship between France and West Africa—French remains the official language in many former French colonies like Senegal, Ivory Coast, and Mali. France continues to invest heavily in cultural initiatives, such as funding schools and universities in these countries, reinforcing its influence. Similarly, Portugal and Brazil maintain close relations through a shared language and cultural heritage, which facilitates ongoing cooperation in education and cultural exchanges. Meanwhile, the Netherlands and Indonesia continue to share connections, with Dutch influence still present in Indonesia’s legal and educational systems. Until recent policy changes, many Indonesian students would pursue higher education in the Netherlands.

Diaspora Communities
The presence of large diaspora communities plays a crucial role in maintaining close ties between former colonies and their colonizers. For instance, the Indian diaspora in the UK numbers in the millions and has significantly impacted UK politics, business, and culture, fostering strong bilateral relations between the two countries. Similarly, France and Algeria share deep connections through the large Algerian diaspora residing in France, which sustains family and economic ties despite the tense history between the nations. Likewise, the Surinamese diaspora in the Netherlands is another example, with migration for education and work playing a vital role in maintaining strong relations between the two countries.

Economic Partnerships and Aid
Economic ties and development aid are essential in maintaining post-colonial relationships. UK-UAE relations are a good example, as British companies are heavily invested in sectors like real estate, finance, and technology in the UAE. The UK's role in the UAE’s development and strategic investments has sustained a strong partnership. Similarly, France and its former colonies in West Africa maintain close economic ties, with France providing aid and financial assistance through mechanisms like the CFA franc, ensuring its continued influence in countries like Burkina Faso and Niger. Portugal’s relationship with East Timor also exemplifies this, with Portugal providing substantial economic aid after East Timor gained independence from Indonesia, further strengthening their ties.

Geopolitical Interests
Geopolitical interests often drive continued close ties between former colonizers and their colonies. For example, France’s military presence in West Africa through initiatives like Operation Barkhane allows France to safeguard its geopolitical interests in the region while combating terrorism. Similarly, the UK maintains its influence over Commonwealth nations such as Australia, Canada, and India, regularly collaborating on international issues like security and trade. Spain’s relationship with Latin American countries like Mexico and Venezuela also has a geopolitical aspect, as Spain seeks to maintain influence in the region through economic and diplomatic ties, often leveraging the shared language and culture to reinforce these relationships.

Shared International Organizations
Former colonies and their colonizers often remain connected through shared memberships in international organizations, which promotes ongoing cooperation. The Commonwealth of Nations, for instance, brings together former British colonies like India, Australia, and South Africa, facilitating political, economic, and cultural exchanges that strengthen ties. Similarly, La Francophonie connects France with its former colonies, such as Senegal, Cameroon, and Vietnam, fostering collaboration in education, culture, and development. The Community of Portuguese Language Countries (CPLP) also promotes cooperation between Portugal and Brazil, further reinforcing their post-colonial relationship through trade, education, and cultural exchange.

Diplomatic Reconciliation and Pragmatism
Many former colonies and their colonizers have made efforts to reconcile and move beyond their colonial histories for the sake of diplomacy and development. India and the UK are a prime example. Despite the difficult legacy of British colonial rule, both nations now enjoy strong diplomatic, economic, and cultural ties, with India being one of the UK’s largest trading partners. Similarly, Brazil and Portugal have developed close diplomatic relations despite Brazil gaining independence in 1822. The two countries regularly collaborate in business, education, and cultural exchanges. New Zealand and the UK also share a strong relationship, built on close diplomatic ties and their shared membership in the Commonwealth, regularly cooperating on issues of trade and security.

Lingering Grievances and Tensions
In some cases, colonial legacies have left deep scars, making reconciliation more difficult. France and Algeria remain a prominent example, with relations strained due to the brutal war of independence and ongoing issues related to immigration and the memory of colonial violence. Similarly, Belgium’s relationship with the Democratic Republic of Congo (DRC) is still tense due to the extreme exploitation and violence that characterized Belgium’s colonial rule. Though diplomatic ties exist, calls for reparations and unresolved historical grievances continue to impact relations. In the case of Indonesia and the Netherlands, relations have improved over time, but tensions occasionally surface, especially regarding the memory of the Indonesian National Revolution (1945–1949) and the legacy of colonial rule. The relationship between Bangladesh and Pakistan is tensed due to (i) India and (ii) the Awami League (BAL). India and Awami League have been enjoying a symbiotic relationship for half a century. India wanted to keep Pakistani influence away, while Awami League wanted total political dominance. Hence, both weaponized the 1971 history and anti-Pakistan rhetoric. That worked very well until BAL leader and ex-PM Sheikh Hasina fled the country.



Solid answer.  I would qualify however that some of these ties, esp. 3 economic ones, cut both way.  For example, the presence of French companies in a FranceAfrique context, and their alleged abuses, often comes up when the recent string of coups is discussed in Mali and other Sahel groups.  ref
